# Setting up a subdomain for hudson while running other sites in II6

Tags: iis-6, hudson

I've installed hudson (http://hudson-ci.org/) on our build server which also doubles as our dev server. All of our development sites are hosted on this machine under IIS6. I'm not sure how hudson hosts itself (is it using apache?) but it listens on port 8080 by default. My server has a domain name attached, say foo.com, so I wanted to set up Hudson so it can run on:

http://hudson.foo.com

But I'm really not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks much.

Comment: I'm right there with you. I'm using Hudson right now in test phase but to go forward I would really like to get it integrated into IIS or at least share it on the same server under port 80.

Answer (score 3):

To give it a subdomain you will have to add a dns record for it. This will have to be done on your dns server.

If IIS is running on port 80 then it will not be able to share with hudson. You will either have to distribute the url as http://hudson.foo.com:8080 or create a site in IIS with the host header of hudson.foo.com which automatically redirects you to port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box version uses Winstone. You can change the port by supplying a start parameter or by changing the hudson.xml (if you installed it as a windows service).

AFAIK, you need to deploy it to an app server if you want to have more options.

Comment: An "app server"? Can you elaborate on what this is and what type of options this will make available?

Comment: Have a look at wikipedia for application server. I mean here of course the java application server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers